# What is the best way to create my own html attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, doctype

I create a lof of attributes on HTML tags to play with jQuery and its `$(selector).attr()` method. For example, if I have a dynamic form with generated fields, I will have a `index="xxx"` attribute.

What is the best way to create such customised attributes without violating doctype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML 5's `data-` attributes might be for you. They're likely to be the easiest way.

Also, [jQuery's `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) supports them natively.

[Here's](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) an article explaining the concept in detail.

An example from that article:

```
<ul id="vegetable-seeds">
  <li data-spacing="10cm" data-sowing-time="March to June">Carrots</li>
  <li data-spacing="30cm" data-sowing-time="February to March">Celery</li>
  <li data-spacing="3cm" data-sowing-time="March to September">Radishes</li>
</ul>
```